# Passing null using $wpdb->insert statement in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this existing code to insert null:

```
if (item['data'] == 'NULL') {
        $item['data'] = NULL;
    }   


     $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'mydata', $item);
```

However I checked in the database and it is just inserting blank as values. I want to insert the real null value with it having checked. Is there some way how to modify my existing code.

If you insert any values , there is a null column in table and if you checked on it , it will give the real null value. But I can hardly figure out how to insert this one. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data should be an array in `column->value` format.

```
$wpdb->insert(
  $wpdb->prefix.'table_name', //param 1 = table name
    array( //param 2 is an array with column name and value
     'column_name' => $yourdata
    )
);
```